# How can I debug why cmake fails with "Compiler is not able to compile a simple test program."

Tags: macos, cmake

I know of a couple of reasons why the initial platform check during `cmake` fails, but can't figure it out in my case, mostly because cmake seems to delete directories it is using for the check.

As an example, I try to compile OpenCV:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/c++ - broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/c++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: custom_dep_location/downloads/opencv-4.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_35974/fast && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/build
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/c++   -Icustom_dep_location/include -Lcustom_dep_location/lib  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fPIE -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c custom_dep_location/downloads/opencv-4.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Lcustom_dep_location/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_35974
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/c++ -Icustom_dep_location/include -Lcustom_dep_location/lib  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_35974 
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lcustom_dep_location/lib'
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_35974] Error 1
    make: *** [cmTC_35974/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:108 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "custom_dep_location/downloads/opencv-4.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "custom_dep_location/downloads/opencv-4.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

So naturally I would like to know what exactly is failing, which tragically is not mentioned. And it seems the temporary folders used for the checks do not actually exist.
When I look into

```
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_35974/fast && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_35974.dir/build
```

I would assume the dirs are relative to the directory cmake was called from (so cwd), but they do not exist, so I cannot rerun the commands manually to get more error messages.
The are also not temporary dirs in `/var/…` or anywhere else on my system

---

How can I make cmake preserve its temporary directories, find them, and manually execute the commands it is trying and failing with?

Comment: I'll note that if you merely wish to use `ccache` with your system C++ compiler you should use `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` instead of a wrapper. That works for make and Ninja... the wrapper would be necessary for Xcode (meh).

Comment: Unrelated, But OpenCVs cmake process does not seem to do that by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I make cmake preserve its temporary directories, find them, and manually execute the commands it is trying and failing with?

Pass `--debug-trycompile` to `cmake`. From [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html):

> Do not delete the `try_compile()` build tree. Only useful on one `try_compile()` at a time.
>
> Do not delete the files and directories created for `try_compile()` calls. This is useful in debugging failed try_compiles. It may however change the results of the try-compiles as old junk from a previous try-compile may cause a different test to either pass or fail incorrectly. This option is best used for one try-compile at a time, and only when debugging.